# Why does searching for flights from a computer in the US give different results from the same search from the UK?

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines, code-share

If I search Virgin Atlantic's website for return flights LHR-PDX in August 2017 I can see the direct flights it offers (operated by Delta as a codeshare) if I'm looking from a UK IP address. But if I perform the same search from a US IP address, only flights with one stop each way (e.g. via SEA or JFK) appear in the results. However, the direct flights are available from Delta's website.

Why is this? How can I ensure that I see all the flights available within a codeshare no matter where I am located when I search?

Comment: The reason may be that if you are from the U.S., the Codeshare Agreement with Delta does not allow Virgin Atlantic to sell to you seats on that plane. Do you find the flight if you search with Delta directly?

Comment: Why does it matter where you search?

Comment: I just did a search from a US IP, and I can see the direct (codeshare) flights.  Sample dates Aug 16th, return Aug 23rd.  http://i.imgur.com/TJpeGOc.png

Comment: Giving advice here because of the downvote risk.  Kayak/Google flights etc very easily allow you to view non-stop only.  Also, be aware that the DL nonstop might not operate every day.

Comment: You're misinterpreting the website!  The first screenshot is showing you the CHEAPEST flights, which is one with stops.  If you select that date, it'll give you the direct (more expensive) and connecting (cheaper) options.

Comment: @Doc Not me. I searched from a US IP address and could not find any way to make the Virgin web site show me the direct flights. OTOH, it comes right up at www.delta.com, and for the same price.

Comment: The availability on a flight (the number of seats available in a particular price range or "fare bucket") is a function of the sales office location amongst several other factors. This location is called the "point of sale". A flight may be nearly full for buyers in London and empty for buyers in NYC. Perhaps you are being redirected to the US site when you have a US IP and the US site uses a US point of sale. However so so far ahead I would be surprised if this was the cause. More likely, there is some caching going on which is dependent on IP and is misrepresenting the flight availability.

Answer (score 2):

If you check Google search engine *ITA* (https://matrix.itasoftware.com/), you will see that they offer a field at the very bottom that reads 'Sales City'. See also the respective Help page (click 'Help' and search for 'Sales City':

> Due to airline business rules, the currency, fares, taxes, fees, and
>   flights available for sale can vary by city. Before searching, make
>   sure that the sales city is accurate so that you get the right
>   information for your location. If left blank, the sales city is set to
>   the departure city of your flight search. Click the Learn more link
>   for additional detail before choosing an alternative sales city.

That alone proves that there *are* intended differences in offers, depending on where you search and buy a flight from. The detailed differences of course depend on each airlines gusto and marketing decisions; sometimes also on their agreements - maybe in you case, Virgin has an agreement with Delta to not offer specific flights to customer starting on one side (and Delta vice versa); you'll never know for sure unless you work in these circles.

Fact is that it is *intended* by the airlines to offer flights *sales location dependent* for different prices or not at all.